# Use powershell to remove a random string of characters from file names

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0

I have a series of files that contain a string of characters such as this

```
(AEDOGRES)
```

An example file name would be

```
"Test 1(DOWKFUET).png"
```

I want to use a powershell command to get rid of the entire string in the parentheses to get something like this.

```
 "Test 1.png"
```

I would expect to be able to use a command like this

```
   dir | rename-item –NewName { $_.name –replace “(*)“,”” }
```

However, this is not working for me. Any help is greatly appreciated!

I am running powershell 3.0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Regex and wildcard matching have different rules.  In regex, the * means "match zero or more of the previous character", and the parens are reserved characters used for grouping constructs and have to be escaped (using a backslash) if you want them to be used as a literal match.

See Get-Help about_regular_expressions, and try this:

```
$name = "Test 1(DOWKFUET).png"
$name -replace '\(.+\)',''
```